# Exception while setting up the wurfl in zend

Tags: zend-framework, exception, wurfl

I have includes all the parameters using the article at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html#zend.http.user-agent.quick-start
but it shows me an exception Unable to resolve plugin "useragent"; no corresponding plugin with that name. My code is :

all configuration in application.ini

```
resources.useragent.storage.adapter = "Session"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.3.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl-php-1.3.1/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.main-file = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/wurfl.xml"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.patches[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/web_browsers_patch.xml"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.provider = "file"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.dir.dir  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/cache/"
```

loaded the files at downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL%20PHP/1.1/wurfl-php-1.1.tar.gz/download
version 1.3.1
    Root_DIR/library/wurfl-php-1.3.1

and created data folder with application and updated with Root_DIR/data/wurfl 
    /chache
    web_browsers_patch.xml
    wurfl.xml

What is i am mising ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was due to version problem. i resolved it after updating version of zend library. it supports on zend V 1.11 and above.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to version problem. i resolved it after updating version of zend library. it supports on zend V 1.11 and above. and after this successful implementation still i am getting an exception like : 
Strict Standards: Declaration of Application_Helper_MobileContext::addActionContext() should be compatible with that of Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ContextSwitch::addActionContext() in /storage/projects/gomotive/application/helpers/MobileContext.php on line 3

But also resolved this by passing default argument value in parent method. check the link below
[Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Hi the solutions is include Zend framework into your library folder.I am facing the same problems and by accidentally i include the Zend Framework v1.11 into library and all works well