# Strict Standards: Declaration of My_Pdf_Document::save() should be compatible with that of Zend_Pdf::save()

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation, zend-pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

I am implementing PDF (Zend_Pdf_Table), downloaded from  [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zendpdftable/)

now the problem is that its giving me following errors.

```
 Error 1=Strict Standards: Declaration of My_Pdf_Document::save() should be compatible 
 with that of Zend_Pdf::save() in D:\SVN data\WebClient_PHP\trunk\library
\My\Pdf\Document.php on line 2
```

Line#2 is

```
class My_Pdf_Document extends My_Pdf{
```

the second error is

```
Error 2=Fatal error: Declaration of My_Pdf_Page::drawImage() must be compatible with
that of Zend_Pdf_Canvas_Interface::drawImage() in D:\SVN data\WebClient_PHP\trunk
\library\My\Pdf\Page.php on line 369
```

some code from my action

```
  $instance   = new abc();
 $select     = $instance->Get_xyz($p);

  try {

  // create PDF
       $pdf = new My_Pdf_Document('Call Logs Details.pdf', '.');

                  // create page
                  $page = $pdf->createPage();

                  // define font resource
                  $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

                  // set font
                  $page->setFont($font, 24);

                  // create table
                  $table = new My_Pdf_Table(3);

                  // iterate over record set
                  // set up table content
                  while ($record = $select->fetch()) {
                    $row = new My_Pdf_Table_Row();
                    $cols = array();
                    foreach ($record as $k => $v) {
                      $col = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();
                      $col->setText($v);
                      $cols[] = $col;
                    }
                    $row->setColumns($cols);
                    $row->setFont($font, 14);
                    $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::TOP, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
                    $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::BOTTOM, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
                    $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::LEFT, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
                    $row->setCellPaddings(array(10,10,10,10));
                    $table->addRow($row);
                  }

                  // add table to page
                  $page->addTable($table, 0, 0);

                  // add page to document
                  $pdf->addPage($page);

                  // save as file
                  $pdf->save();
                  echo 'SUCCESS: Document saved!';
                } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
                  die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                  die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
```

Any idea why i am getting following errors.What i am missing ?? i am using latest Zend framework.

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding those methods with a different signature (the parameters in the method definition).  You cannot override a method in PHP.

This is caused by the signature in My_Pdf_Document being:

```
public function save(){
```

vs the signature in Zend_Pdf being:

```
public function save($filename, $updateOnly = false)
```

Ideally the My_Pdf_Document signature should be updated to match the Zend_Pdf signature.  Note:  This is a Strict error, you could turn off strict errors and ignore it, hoping that everything worked (but I would strongly recommend against doing that).

Comment: so how can i go to accomplish what i want to do ?

Comment: I have edited in more details on the problem.  The rest of the solution is up to you though (unless anyone else has more specific help).

Comment: so shall i change the signature ??

Comment: Just change the signature in your version to match, and ensure you are passing those parameters up to the parent class if you call the parent method from your version.

Answer (score 1):

The library you are attempting to use is not completely compatible with ZF 1.11, also, it does not appear the author of that component was using `error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL)`.  My suggestion to you is to download that codebase, correct it for `error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL)` where appropriate (as others have noted here - effectively, make sure all the child method signature match their parents method signature).

If the original author is still around and cares for keeping it updated, commit it back to them.