# cakephp PHP 5.4.4

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

I just installed php 5.4.4. and I all of a sudden get a strict warning.
Does someone know what it is?

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of User::beforeSave() should be compatible with Model::beforeSave($options = Array) [APP/Model/User.php, line 3]
```

Comment: What is unclear of the message?

Comment: That is for what normally interfaces are for, but instead of static stacking, I suggest you switch to [`Super::$tatic`](http://i.imgur.com/RJEsz.png) sooner or later. It is just the way to do PHP cake or anything else.

Comment: Also please contact the software vendor and ask in support if PHP 5.4.4. is supported by cakephp. Not that you use an unsupported PHP version with your framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In APP/Model/User.php, change the declaration to match the class it extends, Model

```
function beforeSave( array $options ){
    ...
```

Comment: public function beforeValidate($options=array()) {}

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, you'll notice that the methods signature differs. Model::beforeSave() accepts an optional array, whilst your method doesn't accept anything.

However, the message is not severe. It's a strict, meaning that you're breaking standards, but is not like you're on Titanic.

Comment: " but is not like you're on Titanic" -> Yes he is. He's using Cake. It's the Titanic and it's sinking fast! ;)

Comment: It means that you are *on* Titanic, but the ice-block is somewhere in the future to illustrate that picture a bit ;)

Comment: "Strict standards? BAH haha, this app is unsinkable! UNSINKABLE!"