# PHP: "Declaration of ... should be compatible with that of ..."

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like to create an interface for entities that are CRUDable (can be saved and deleted). Here is my abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractCrudableEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    abstract public function doSave();
    abstract public function doDelete();
}
```

My implementing class needs a couple extra parameters to those methods. Here is the signature of the implementing class:

```
class Contact extends AbstractCrudableEntity {
    public function doSave(User $user, \UberClientManager $manager);
    public function doDelete(User $user, \UberClientManager $manager);
}
```

I understand that PHP requires that implementing classes have the same parameters for the methods as the parent class (there are several questions that answer this question: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php), for example). So that is not the problem.

However, I recently came across some code in Symfony dealing with authentication tokens. The class `UsernamePasswordToken` extends `AbstractToken`, and has a different set of parameters in the `__construct()` method: [`AbstractToken::__construct()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php#L38) versus [`UsernamePasswordToken::__construct()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php#L34).

My question is how is Symfony able to do this? What is the difference between this and my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding constructors is a [special case](http://php.net/construct):

> Unlike with other methods, PHP will not generate an `E_STRICT` level error message when `__construct()` is overridden with different parameters than the parent `__construct()` method has.

You can *not* do that with other methods.

Comment: Wow, I wonder why the constructor is a special case. It seems like they recognized that this functionality is useful, but for some reason limited it to just the constructor.

Comment: [Welcome to the beautiful world of PHP](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/). ;)

Comment: Ugh, it's only a matter of time before someone posts that link in a PHP question.

Comment: Just the case for that link. It hurts.

Answer (score 0):

Your child methods must have the same number of parameters as the abstract methods in an abstract parent class.

The constructor in you example is not abstract--the child is just overriding it.

Comment: This doesn't matter. In fact, I tried declaring the methods in `AbstractCrudableEntity` as not abstract, and still got the error.