# Same Laravel resource controller for multiple routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, dry

I am trying to use a trait as a typehint for my Laravel resource controllers.

The controller method:

```
public function store(CreateCommentRequest $request, Commentable $commentable)
```

In which the `Commentable` is the trait typehint which my Eloquent models use.

The `Commentable` trait looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models\Morphs;

use App\Comment;

trait Commentable
{
   /**
    * Get the model's comments.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
    */
    public function Comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

In my routing, I have:

```
Route::resource('order.comment', 'CommentController')
Route::resource('fulfillments.comment', 'CommentController')
```

Both orders and fulfillments can have comments and so they use the same controller since the code would be the same.

However, when I post to `order/{order}/comment`, I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>   **Target [App\Models\Morphs\Commentable] is not instantiable.**

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Looks like automatic resolving your Dependency failed. Please provide code of your `Commentable` file.

Comment: @manniL, I've updated the description with the content of Commentable

Comment: Well, why don't you use a real "Comment" model instead? That would work :D

Comment: Commentable could be a an Order or a Fufillment

Comment: Yeah, but if you use a [Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) it shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: Wrong use of emoticons, wrong use, wrong, wrong, just wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you want to avoid duplicate code for both order and fulfillment resource controllers and be a bit DRY. Good.

#### Traits cannot be typehinted

As Matthew [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129140/65732), you can't typehint traits and that's the reason you're getting the binding resolution error. Other than that, even if it was typehintable, the container would be confused which model it should instantiate as there are two `Commentable` models available. But, we'll get to it later.

#### Interfaces alongside traits

It's often a good practice to have an interface to accompany a trait. Besides the fact that interfaces can be typehinted, you're adhering to the [Interface Segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) principle which, "if needed", is a good practice.

```php
interface Commentable 
{
    public function comments();
}

class Order extends Model implements Commentable
{
    use Commentable;

    // ...
}
```

Now that it's typehintable. Let's get to the container confusion issue.

#### Contexual binding

Laravel's container supports [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#contextual-binding). That's the ability to explicitly tell it when and how to resolve an abstract to a concrete.

The only distinguishing factor you got for your controllers, is the route. We need to build upon that. Something along the lines of:

```php
# AppServiceProvider::register()
$this->app
    ->when(CommentController::class)
    ->needs(Commentable::class)
    ->give(function ($container, $params) {
        // Since you're probably utilizing Laravel's route model binding, 
        // we need to resolve the model associated with the passed ID using
        // the `findOrFail`, instead of just newing up an empty instance.

        // Assuming this route pattern: "order|fullfilment/{id}/comment/{id}"
        $id = (int) $this->app->request->segment(2);

        return $this->app->request->segment(1) === 'order'
            ? Order::findOrFail($id)
            : Fulfillment::findOrFail($id);
     });
```

You're basically telling the container when the `CommentController` requires a `Commentable` instance, first check out the route and then instantiate the correct commentable model.

Non-contextual binding will do as well:

```php
# AppServiceProvider::register()
$this->app->bind(Commentable::class, function ($container, $params) {
    $id = (int) $this->app->request->segment(2);

    return $this->app->request->segment(1) === 'order'
        ? Order::findOrFail($id)
        : Fulfillment::findOrFail($id);
});
```

#### Wrong tool

We've just eliminated duplicate controller code by introducing unnecessary complexity which is as worse as that.

[image]

Even though it works, it's complex, not maintainable, non-generic and worst of all, dependent to the URL. It's using the wrong tool for the job and is plain wrong.

#### Inheritance

The right tool to eliminate these kinda problems is simply inheritance. Introduce an abstract base comment controller class and extend two shallow ones from it.

```php
# App\Http\Controllers\CommentController
abstract class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(CreateCommentRequest $request, Commentable $commentable) {
        // ...
    }

    // All other common methods here...
}

# App\Http\Controllers\OrderCommentController
class OrderCommentController extends CommentController
{
    public function store(CreateCommentRequest $request, Order $commentable) {
        return parent::store($commentable);
    }
}

# App\Http\Controllers\FulfillmentCommentController
class FulfillmentCommentController extends CommentController
{
    public function store(CreateCommentRequest $request, Fulfillment $commentable) {
        return parent::store($commentable);
    }
}

# Routes
Route::resource('order.comment', 'OrderCommentController');
Route::resource('fulfillments.comment', 'FulfillCommentController');
```

Simple, flexible and maintainable.

#### Arrrgh, wrong language

Not so fast:

> Declaration of **OrderCommentController::store(CreateCommentRequest $request, Order $commentable)** should be compatible with **CommentController::store(CreateCommentRequest $request, Commentable $commentable)**.

Even though overriding method parameters works in the constructors just fine, it simply does not for other methods! Constructors are [special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13158328/65732).

We could just drop the typehints in both parent and child classes and go on with our lives with plain IDs. But in that case, as Laravel's implicit model binding only works with typehints, there won't be any automatic model loading for our controllers.

Ok, maybe in a better world.

[image]

*Update: See [PHP 7.4](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/php-7.4.0RC1/UPGRADING)'s support for type variance*

#### Explicit route model binding

So what we gonna do?

If we explicitly tell the router how to load our `Commentable` models, we can just use the lone `CommentController` class. Laravel's [explicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#explicit-binding) works by mapping route placeholders (e.g. `{order}`) to model classes or custom resolution logics. So, while we're using our single `CommentController` we can utilize separate models or resolution logics for orders and fulfillments based on their route placeholders. So, we drop the typehint and rely on the placeholder.

For resource controllers, the placeholder name depends on the first parameter you pass to the `Route::resource` method. Just do a `artisan route:list` to find out.

Ok, let's do it:

```php
# App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()
public function boot()
{
    // Map `{order}` route placeholder to the \App\Order model
    $this->app->router->model('order', \App\Order::class);

    // Map `{fulfillment}` to the \App\Fulfilment model
    $this->app->router->model('fulfillment', \App\Fulfilment::class);

    parent::boot();
}
```

Your controller code would be:

```php
# App\Http\Controllers\CommentController
class CommentController extends Controller
{
    // Note that we have dropped the typehint here:
    public function store(CreateCommentRequest $request, $commentable) {
        // $commentable is either an \App\Order or a \App\Fulfillment
    }

    // Drop the typehint from other methods as well.
}
```

And the route definitions remain the same.

It's better than the first solution, as it does not rely on the URL segments which are prone to change contrary to the route placeholders which rarely change. It's also generic as all `{order}`s will be resolved to `\App\Order` model and all `{fulfillment}`s to the `App\Fulfillment`.

We could alter the first solution to utilize route parameters instead of URL segments. But there's no reason to do it manually when Laravel has provided it to us.

---

Yeah, I know, I don't feel good, too.

Comment: I took the inheritance approach, great answer. Can you make an example of what the store method of OrderCommentController would look like? I can't typehint Order, because it has to be compatible with the parent method.

Comment: @sepehr Nice summary of available options.

Comment: @sepehr Great answer, I'd give 100 upvotes if it was possible. I went with the route model binding option and it worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't typehint traits](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

However, you can typehint interfaces. So you can create an interface that requires the methods from the trait and resolve that. Then have your classes implement that interface and you should be OK.

EDIT: As @Stefan has kindly pointed out, it's still likely to be difficult to resolve the interface to a concrete class because it will need to resolve to different classes under different circumstances. You could access the request in the service provider and use the path to determine how to resolve it, but I'm a bit dubious of that. I think putting them in separate controllers and using inheritance/traits to share common functionality may be a better bet, since the methods in each controller can type hint the required object, and then pass them to the equivalent parent method.

Comment: I'm making the assumption, that the DIC should resolve Commentable. If Commentable is an interface and multiple concrete classes fullfil the interface by using the CommentableTrait, then how does the DIC know which concrete class to instantiate?

Comment: @Stefan Good point. It might well be troublesome to resolve it to the required class under these circumstances unless you access the request in the service provider and resolve it differently based on the URL, which is a bit too hacky for my liking. It's probably safer to have separate controllers.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I have following resources:

```
        Route::resource('books/storybooks', 'BookController');
        Route::resource('books/magazines', 'BookController');
```

After php artisan route:cache and it creates the route to tie up with 'magazine' model.

The solution is to add following line in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php > boot() method, after parent::boot():

```
        Route::model('magazine', \App\Book::class);
```

Pay attention to the singular and plural.