# CakePHP and Mognodb

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.2.4 and Mongodb 2.2.2

I have worked through a couple of issues but am getting the following errors on my cakephp homepage

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of MongodbSource::execute() should be compatible with DboSource::execute($sql, $options = Array, $params = Array) [APP/Plugin/Mongodb/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php, line 36]
```

I get a similar error for these function declarations

- MongodbSource::query()
- MongodbSource::create()
- MongodbSource::read()
- MongodbSource::update()
- MongodbSource::delete()
- MongodbSource::calculate()
- MongodbSource::group()
- MongodbSource::dropSchema()
- MongodbSource::describe()

MongodbSource extends DbSource

in DbSource:

```
public function execute($sql, $options = array(), $params = array()) { <code here> }
```

in MongodbSource:

```
public function execute($query, $params = array()) { <code here> }
```

I kind of understand whats going on but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Ok I have gotten past the error by updating cakephp, /app/Config/core.php and adding `& ~E_STRICT` to the ErrorHandler.  I realize that this isn't Best Practices and doesn't fix the problem.  I still want to know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods that override parent methods should implement the same arguments, ie your `execute` methods signature in `MongodbSource` should be:

```
public function execute($sql, $options = array(), $params = array())
```

See also:

[Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

https://www.google.com/search?q=php+Declaration+of+should+be+compatible+with

http://php.net/manual/en/migration51.oop.php#migration51.oop-inheritance

Comment: Spot on.  We also found some code changes that were submitted at the github site that addressed most of the issues.  https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/pull/65