# Strict Standards: Declaration of Response::toXML() error

Tags: php, plivo

I have the follow error which shows in a PHP script.

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Response::toXML() should 
be compatible with Element::toXML($header = false) in line 35
```

The line in question is `require_once ('./plivo.php');`; an import of the plivo.com PHP helper.

Can anyone tell me what this error is and how I might fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have already figured this out, but in case you actually want to fix the error instead of changing the level of error reporting you need to change the following:

```
// In the plivo.php helper file we're looking at
// the Response class that extends the Element class
// Change the following function from:
public function toXML() {
    $xml = parent::toXML($header=TRUE);
    return $xml;
}

// To:
public function toXML($header=TRUE) {
    $xml = parent::toXML($header);
    return $xml;
}
```

The issue is the childClass::method() has different arguments to the parentClass::method() as outlined in [notJim's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php). Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and it caused me the same issue. I removed it and now I am using `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` The error occurs due to `E_STRICT`. more info for error_reporting at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php