# PHP 5.4 Strict Standards How make disparate, unordered parameters of child method compatible with parent method?

Tags: php, methods, joomla, standards-compliance

I am debugging a Joomla site, using old Joomla 2.5 . On the move to php 5.4 we encountered the widely discussed strict standards errors. Most have been easy to fix. I have one last error that is proving more difficult.

> Strict Standards: Declaration of JCacheControllerView::get() should be
>   compatible with JCacheController::get($id, $group = NULL) in
>   /home/XXXXXX/public_testing/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/view.php
>   on line 137

Research shows advice such as this:
[Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php/9243127#9243127)

JCacheController defines

```
public function get($id, $group = null)
```

JCacheControllerView extends JCacheController and defines:

```
public function get(&$view, $method, $id = false, $wrkarounds = true)
```

So I tried changing the declarations to have the same parameters and same default values:
JCacheController defines

```
public function get($id=false, $group = null, &$view = null, $method = null, $wrkarounds = true)
```

JCacheControllerView extends JCacheController and defines:

```
public function get(&$view = null, $method = null, $id = false, $wrkarounds = true, $group = null)
```

Which results in:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of JCacheControllerView::get() should be
>   compatible with JCacheController::get($id = false, $group = NULL,
>   &$view = NULL, $method = NULL, $wrkarounds = true) in
>   /home/freedibl/public_testing/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/view.php
>   on line 137

Could this be because the parameters are not in the same order? How could I fix this without altering the original method calls? Both methods are widely used, and it would be difficult to change every call to either one throughout joomla.

Answer (score 0):

The order of parameters doesn't matter for PHP interpreter per se as it doesn't check parameters compatibility by name. But you have different *types* of parameters. Some of them are references and some are variables - this makes declarations incompatible.

So, you actually can fix this problem by changing the parameters order so the types match in both declarations.

Is `$view` parameter an object or a simple type? If it's an object, you probably don't have to pass it as a reference at all.

Comment: The error stopped showing (I'm uncomfortable with errors coming and going, is this a Joomla issue?). If it reappears, I will definitely remove the reference. Thanks for your help.