# Declaration of Method should be Compatible with CActiveRecord Method

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii Framework and Developing an Application, I am having the following error when logging into the my application

> Declaration of User::update() should be compatible with CActiveRecord::update($attributes = NULL)

While it was not getting before, I stopped working on the application for a week but after a week this is happening to me.

In my LIVE Server it is working fine while at localhost it is giving me the error.

I tried to google it and found the following StackOverflow Question
[Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

But this Q/A did not solve my problem as this solution tells me to change every function while the same application on my LIVE Server is running smoothly.

Sorry for the English.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function in your User model to

```
update($attributes = null) { //bla }
```

instead of

```
update() { //bla }
```

Just like the error says the declaration of the function should be compatible with the one earlier defined in the parent class.

Comment: update function in my User model is like update($params = array(), $id){ //bla }

Comment: that's why this is happening, but at my live server it is working fine.

Comment: Then probably there is a difference in PHP version or error settings.