# Declaration of UsersController::beforeFilter() should be compatible with AppController::beforeFilter(Cake\Event\Event $event)

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I am not experienced with cakephp ver3.1.3

I followed the instructions to implement login authentication function;
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I managed to successfully cake bake my cakephp v3.1.3 app.

I have a problem with UsersController.php

I have the following code copied and pasted from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html;

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
    // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
    $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);
} //public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
```

The presence of this code created the error below;

> Strict (2048): Declaration of
>   App\Controller\UsersController::beforeFilter() should be compatible
>   with App\Controller\AppController::beforeFilter(Cake\Event\Event
>   $event) [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 12] Code Context
>   include - APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 12
>   Composer\Autoload\includeFile - ROOT\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php,
>   line 412 Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass() -
>   ROOT\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php, line 301 spl_autoload_call -
>   [internal], line ?? class_exists - [internal], line ??
>   Cake\Core\App::_classExistsInBase() - CORE\src\Core\App.php, line 89
>   Cake\Core\App::className() - CORE\src\Core\App.php, line 66
>   Cake\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter::_getController() -
>   CORE\src\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter.php, line 81
>   Cake\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter::beforeDispatch() -
>   CORE\src\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter.php, line 49
>   Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter::handle() -
>   CORE\src\Routing\DispatcherFilter.php, line 145
>   Cake\Event\EventManager::_callListener() -
>   CORE\src\Event\EventManager.php, line 389
>   Cake\Event\EventManager::dispatch() - CORE\src\Event\EventManager.php,
>   line 355 Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatchEvent() -
>   CORE\src\Event\EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
>   Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php,
>   line 62 [main] - ROOT\webroot\index.php, line 37

If I remove the offending code segment, the error disappears. What is wrong with the code segment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

Comment: *Read* the error message. It already tells you pretty clearly what is wrong. If you still can't understand it try to search for it. This is a standard php message and has been asked a felt 1000 times before on Stackoverflow. I've voted to close it as duplicate for that reason.

Comment: @ burzum, thanks. Let me study more carefully.

Comment: This is not a CakePHP issue, but a PHP one. As the error message states your inherited method is not compatible with its parent.

Comment: It is **not** related to CakePHP. This is simply how **php** works. If you would have searched for the error, you would have realized this gets asked for Wordpress, Joomla and a lot other scripts. You still have not understood what the error means and why it happens. You probably don't understand how namespaces work either. Let me rephrase the error messages: Make the method signatures match.

Comment: @burzum, You are right. Pardon my ignorance. I am still a newbie in php and cakephp. It is possible to get things done without real understanding due to so much workable sample code out there today.

Comment: To copy and pasting code *without understanding* it is a *very bad* habit. It won't gain you anything and it will, in the worst case, introduce serious issues in a script. Just read the manuals, php and CakePHP have awesome documentation, especially compared to many other things, you just have to read it. I strongly recommend you to change your habit and learn how to learn before learning programming.

Comment: @burzum, absolutely agree. Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution is to add the following line to UsersController.php

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
```

The cake baked version does not have the above line.

Answer (score 8):

On Cake 4.0.2 Strawberry - it is now -

```
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;

public function beforeFilter(EventInterface  $event)
        {
            parent::beforeFilter($event);
    }
```