# Declaration should be compatible with PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded my site to PHP 7 and now get this error on the frontend:

```
Warning: Declaration of Works_Walker::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Category::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0)
```

The code that this refers to is:

```
 class Works_Walker extends Walker_Category {
 function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args)
```

When I edit this code to match the parent I get a syntax error.

```
class Works_Walker extends Walker_Category {
function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0)
```

The "Array" seems to be the cause of the syntax error. I hope this is helpful info for a diagnosis.

Comment: It tells you right in the message. Your function signature must match the interface/function signature you're extending. This includes "default" values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. Unfortunately I can't find any code reference in my site to Walker_Category other than the code I posted earlier. I'm not sure where I can change these signatures to match them.

Comment: You're extending Walker Category and overriding a parent method. To properly override it, your signature must match. Since I presume you don't want to change the parent, you must change the child.

Comment: I tried to change the child function to the same as the parent but I get a syntax error. Not sure why that is the case.

Comment: I can't help without knowing the syntax error and how you changed it. You could update the question, although it might now be a bit out of scope of the original problem.

Comment: I've edited the post, let me know if that is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` is a type. You're looking for `array()` (or `[]`), since you're assigning a default *value*. I.e. `$args = Array` should be `$args = array()`. For reference:
[4.7.2/Walker_Category](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-includes/class-walker-category.php#L98)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you for your help.