# Message: Declaration of Admin::delete($id = '') should be compatible with Core::delete($tbl, $database, $param, $id)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

Severity: Warning

Message: Declaration of Admin::delete($id = '') should be compatible with Core::delete($tbl, $database, $param, $id)

Filename: controllers/admin.php

Controller Admin:

```
   function delete($id='')
{
    core::delete('admin','gammu','ID',$id);
    redirect('admin');
}}
```

Core:

```
function delete($tbl,$database,$param,$id)
{
    $this->model->delete($tbl,$database,$param,$id);
}
```

Comment: what does that `core::delete` will do ? `core` is your model name ?

Comment: Sorry I got a wrong input

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php). Method(s and properties) of Admin class should be compatible with method(s and properties) of Core class as parent class. Parent Core class delete() method has different arguments than you use in Admin class delete() method.