# php Strict Standards: Declaration of () should be compatible with () in ... on line 487

Tags: php

My problem is  Declaration error
I read other some problem but none of them aren't solve my problem.
I don't want  hide this error notice.How I can do solve this error? 
My error notice is;

> Strict Standards: Declaration of MyFilesPolicy::getFileList() should
>   be compatible with MyFile::getFileList($area = false, $extra_filter =
>   false, $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) in
>   /forum/lib/lib.myfiles.php
>   on line ..

**Class Myfile{**

```
function getFileList($area = false, $extra_filter = false, $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) {

    $query = "
    SELECT ".implode(', ', $this->arr_field)."
    FROM ".$this->getFilesTable()."
    WHERE owner = '".$this->id_user."'";
    if($area !== false) $query .= " AND area = '".$area."'";
    if($extra_filter !== false) $query .= $extra_filter;
    if($order_by !== false) $query .= " ORDER BY ".$this->arr_field[$order_by]."";
    else $query .= " ORDER BY title";

    if($from !== false) {
        $query .= " LIMIT ".$from.", ".$num_elem;
    }

    $re_query = $this->_query($query);
    return $re_query;
}
}
```

**class MyFilesPolicy extends MyFile {**

```
function getFileList($area = false, $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) {

    $arr_policy = array( MF_POLICY_FREE );
    if($this->isViewerFriend() || $this->_viewer == $this->_id_user) {
        $arr_policy[] = MF_POLICY_FRIENDS;
        $arr_policy[] = MF_POLICY_TEACHER_AND_FRIENDS;
    }
    if($this->isViewerTeacher() || $this->_viewer == $this->_id_user) {
        $arr_policy[] = MF_POLICY_TEACHER;
        $arr_policy[] = MF_POLICY_TEACHER_AND_FRIENDS;
    }
    if($this->_viewer == $this->_id_user) $arr_policy = array(  MF_POLICY_FREE,MF_POLICY_NOONE );

    $query = "
    SELECT ".implode(', ', $this->arr_field)."
    FROM ".$this->getFilesTable()."
    WHERE owner = '".$this->_id_user."'
        AND ".$this->arr_field[MYFILE_POLICY]." IN ( ".implode(',', $arr_policy)." ) ";
    if($area !== false) $query .= " AND area = '".$area."'";
    if($order_by !== false) $query .= " ORDER BY ".$this->arr_field[$order_by]."";
    else $query .= " ORDER BY title";
    if($from !== false) {
        $query .= " LIMIT ".$from.", ".$num_elem;
    }

    $re_query = $this->_query($query);
    return $re_query;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the parameter `$extra_filter` from the parameter list in the extended class

```
function getFileList($area = false, $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) {
```

So add it like this

```
function getFileList($area = false, $extra_filter = false, $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) {
```

Comment: does not it cause the fault?

should I always fix it this way for similar errors ?

Answer (score 0):

spot the difference, I've given a slight hint for you:

Class Myfile

```
function getFileList($area = false, $extra_filter = false, $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) {
```

Class MyFilesPolicy

```
function getFileList($area = false,                        $order_by = false, $from = false, $num_elem = false) {
```

as the error says:

> MyFilesPolicy::getFileList() should be compatible with
>   MyFile::getFileList()

Comment: I found it, thank you answer but I thought it would cause another mistake

Comment: duplicate post? maybe this will clarify  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php