# when trying to connect mongoDB with kohana i am getting this i searched through website but not find solution

Tags: mongodb, kohana-3.3

when trying to connect mongoDB with kohana i get error and i searched through google but not find solution.

> ErrorException [ Warning ]: Declaration of
>   Kohana_Model_Database::factory($name, $db = NULL) should be compatible
>   with Model_Mongo::factory($model, $id = NULL, $config = 'default')

Comment: What library you use? This Warning mean, that `Model_Mongo` extends `Kohana_Model_Database` and method `factory` has different argument count or acces level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)