# PHP Warning: Declaration of xyy::query($query) should be compaitble with mysqli::query($query, $resultmode = NULL) in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to write a wrapper class for mysqli, basically just to better handle errors, but I'm getting an error when I try to run any page on the website, not just specifically ones that call mysqli.

this is the error I get:

> PHP Warning:  Declaration of PricingMySql::query($query) should be compatible with mysqli::query($query, $resultmode = NULL) in \classes\PricingMySql.php on line 37

This is the class definition for PricingMySql:

```
class PricingMySql extends mysqli{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(Pricing_DBServerName, Pricing_UserName,
            Pricing_Password, Pricing_DBName);
    if($this->connect_errno){
        throw new Exception("Failed to connect to MySQL: (". $this->connect_errno. ") ". $this->connect_error, $this->connect_errno);
    }
}

public function query(string $query, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
    if(!$result  = parent::query($query, $resultmode)) {
        echo "Query Execution failed: (", $this->connect_errno, ") ", $query;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

According to php.net, the definition of the mysqli::query method is exactly the same

```
 mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] ) : mixed
```

So why then do I get the warning? I tried changing my code so that $resultmode = null like it says in the warning:

```
public function query(string $query, int $resultmode = NULL) {
```

but that still results in the same warning. Where am I going wrong?

Edit to add: I got rid of the forced types:

```
public function query($query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
```

but again, same warning.

Comment: The clue is in the error... Mysql vs. Mysqli

Comment: `MySql::query($query)` should be compatible with `mysqli::query`

Comment: Somewhere you are using a mysql() function and then mysqli() function... or similar.. but can't see it in your code... Post more code.

Comment: You have extended the `MYSQLI` Class and then you have tried to redefine the prototype of `MYSQLI::query()` It wont let you do that. Look at the prototype of [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: My bad.. read it wrong... PricingMySql::query($query, null) <--- you've tried that?

Comment: Get rid of the forced types (`string` and `int`) in the signature. Sometimes less is more.

Comment: I did get rid of the forced types, it still gives the same warning.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have tried this PricingMySql::query($query, null) not in the method declaration but the method call?

Comment: @Dammeul it doesn't even get that far. This warning occurs when the PricingMySql.php class is loaded via require_once();  Besides, what would be the point of having a default on the parameter if it's going to cause an error when you don't use it in the call?

Comment: OK, so it's been marked as a duplicate, but reading that duplicate does not help at all. my definition and the definition in php.net are exactly the same! why do I still get this warning then?

Answer (score -1):

If you're declaration is:

```
PricingMySql::query($query)
```

And the actual method is:

```
mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Then you're missing the second parameter.

Try `PricingMySql::query($query, null)` if you haven't already.

This link provides more information: [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)

Comment: if you look at my code above you'll see I am including the second parameter in my method.

Comment: So you don't have a line of code doing this then: PricingMySql::query($query)?

Comment: You're passing one parameter, it takes two.

Comment: just adding a secondary paramenter on `query($query)` method to `query($query, $resultmode = NULL)`  inside the `mysqli` class resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Indeed. Feel free to mark as the correct answer given that it was indeed missing the second parameter.